# Unable to sync gradle project in Android 3.4

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization, access-denied

[image]

I am unable to sync my Project in Android Studio 3.4. I checked many solutions on the internet. I didn't get one that fixes mine.

I tried invalidate cache / Restart. But it didn't work out.

Comment: Post your error log. `Access Denied` can't be your error log.

Comment: have you tried a new android studio installation ? just delete and install again ?